Issue with Bursting Query in Oracle HCM Report: "There is no data to process" Error
I have created a report in Oracle that outputs data correctly when run on its own. However, when I attach a bursting query and run it through an ESS job, I receive the error: "There is no data to process", even though there is data available.
Here is the bursting query I am using:
SELECT '1' AS KEY,
       'Department Delete Report' AS TEMPLATE,
       'TEXT' AS OUTPUT_FORMAT,
       'en' AS LOCALE,
       'FTP' AS DEL_CHANNEL,
       'DEV2_V2' AS PARAMETER1,
       NULL AS PARAMETER2,
       NULL AS PARAMETER3,
       '/home/in' AS PARAMETER4,
       'Department_Delete_' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') || '_' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HHMMSS') || '.csv' AS PARAMETER5,
       'true' AS PARAMETER6 -- secure FTP or not
FROM DUAL;

I have verified that the report runs fine and produces data without the bursting and produces data. The bursting query seems correct, and I'm using the following setup for the FTP output file.
Despite these efforts, the ESS job always returns the "There is no data to process" error. Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong?
Thanks!

Try double-quotes around KEY... select '1' as "KEY".

Hi @Isolated - I tried this but it is still erroring out

Could it be an authorisation issue? Can you verify that the user running the ESS job has proper permissions?

Your bursting query needs to have the real data from your report's DataModel. Select your bursting columns from your DataModel's query (instead of from Dual) and ensure that the KEY column bursting data is the right one to be compared to DELIIVER BY data defined in bursting definition section of your DataModel.
The thing is that the bursting query's "KEY" column should have  the data from your DataModel's query column that you defined as DELIVER BY in bursting definition. We don't know your query and don't know your SPLIT BY / DELIVER BY columns so you should adjust it. Your bursting query should be something like here:
SELECT your_deliver_by_column_here AS KEY,       -- KEY is compared to DELIVER BY at the execution
       'Department Delete Report' AS TEMPLATE,
       'TEXT' AS OUTPUT_FORMAT,
       'en' AS LOCALE,
       'FTP' AS DEL_CHANNEL,
       'DEV2_V2' AS PARAMETER1,
       NULL AS PARAMETER2,
       NULL AS PARAMETER3,
       '/home/in' AS PARAMETER4,
       'Department_Delete_' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD') || '_' || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HHMMSS') || '.csv' AS PARAMETER5,
       'true' AS PARAMETER6 -- secure FTP or not
FROM ( ... your DataModels sql (or part of it) having Deliver By data ... );    -- instead of Dual 

If you execute this query (SQLDeveloper) it should result with the rows of data with KEY column populated with the data from the report.
See more about bursting with some examples - here.
